# subset columns in a data frame by a row value using select in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to subset a data frame by the entry in the first row. For example:

```
col1 <- c("blue", 2, "small")
col2 <- c("red", 4, "large")
col3 <- c("green", 3, "medium")

df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)
```

... I'd like to subset df to just col2 based on the first entry being "red". If there were two columns that matched that criteria, eg:

```
col1 <- c("blue", 2, "small")
col2 <- c("red", 4, "large")
col3 <- c("green", 3, "medium")
col4 <- c("red", 5, "small")

df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

... cols 2 & 4 should be returned.

I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539419/r-how-to-make-a-subset-of-columns-based-on-values-in-a-row-in-a-data-frame) to my question - the answer's 5 years' old so I'm hoping there's a far more elegant way by using `select` in `dplyr`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could just select them without dplyr.

```
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4)    
df[,df[1,] == "red", drop = F]
#    col2  col4
# 1   red   red
# 2     4     5
# 3 large small
```